# How to efficiently compute the column-wise outer vector in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that the matrix `A` has the size `m x r` and that `B` has `n x r`. In `NumPy`, how can I do column-wise outer-product between `A` and `B`?

That is, I want a matrix, `C` (size: `m x n x r`), where `C[:, :, i]` is the outer product of `A[:, i]` and `B[:, i]`.

Of course, I can use a `for` loop over the columns but I am wondering if there is a vectorized way to make the computation fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually call on [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for easy vectorization in cases like this:

```
>>> m,n,r = 30,50,70
>>> A = np.random.random((m,r))
>>> B = np.random.random((n,r))
>>> C = np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk', A, B)
>>> C2 = np.dstack([np.outer(A[:,i], B[:,i]) for i in range(r)])
>>> C.shape
(30, 50, 70)
>>> np.allclose(C, C2)
True
```

This way we can be explicit about what we want to happen to each coordinate, while still being faster than a loop:

```
>>> %timeit C = np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk', A, B)
The slowest run took 4.83 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 216 µs per loop

>>> %timeit C2 = np.dstack([np.outer(A[:,i], B[:,i]) for i in range(r)])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.08 ms per loop
```